# Is there a way to change the background color of a parent element when a radio button is clicked without jQuery?

Tags: css, reactjs

The code structure looks somewhat like this

```js
     function RenderOptions() {
      return allOptions.map((val) => {
        return (
          <>
            <label htmlFor={val}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="options"
                id={val}
                value={val}
                className="check-btn"
              />{" "}
              <span className="text-inner">{val}</span>
            </label>{" "}
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
          </>
        );
      });
    }
```

Didn't put a div since I didn't want to spend some time finding how to align the buttons in rows.

**CSS**

```css
.check-btn {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

label {
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Inter;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s ease;

  background: #f5f7fb;
  border: 0.794239px solid #4d5b9e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 7.94239px;

  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

label:hover {
  background-color: #d6dbf5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-inner {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
}
```

I'm trying to change the **background color** of the parent **label** when the radio button is **checked**. Can do it the CSS way or the React way provided only 1 button from each sets color changes.

[image: image|680x500, 50%]

and if another option is clicked ->

[image: image|690x475, 50%]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR.** See the CodePen sample I prepared for you [here](https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/bGYxoQL), and the snippet below.

In this example, I simply used the `useState` hook to keep track of the current radio selection, and applied its value as `data` attribute to `label` tag. Then you can use CSS to style it as needed.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [chosenOne, setChosenOne] = React.useState();
  const list = ["Alec Baldwin", "Bruce Willis", "Dwayne Johnson", "Jamie Fox"];
  
  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((person, i) => (
        <label key={i} htmlFor={person} data-chosen={chosenOne === person}>
          <input type="radio" name="options" id={person} value={person} className="check-btn" onChange={(e) => setChosenOne(e.target.value)}/>
          <span className="text-inner">{person}</span>
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```css
.check-btn {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

label {
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Inter;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s ease;

  background: #f5f7fb;
  border: 0.794239px solid #4d5b9e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 7.94239px;

  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

label:hover, label[data-chosen="true"] {
  background-color: #d6dbf5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-inner {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
}

label + label {
  margin-left: .5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with CSS or the style prop in React.

I'm assuming your storing the state of the radio buttons somewhere?

When you map through the array, you can check if the current radio button's value is equal to the value of the current state. If they are the same, you can add the class or style to style the label.